# Reference to the sukkah in the Shabbat reading of Chol haMoed?

Tags: torah-reading, sukkot, sukkah, parashat-ki-tisa, mishnah-berurah

The Shulchan Arukh (OC 663:3) says that on Shabbat of Chol haMoed Sukkot (as with the Shabbat of Chol haMoed Pesach) we read from Exodus 33-34. This is learnt out from a baraita in Megillah 31a, although no reason is given. The Chofetz Chayim (Mishna Berurah, 663:8) says that it is because there is a reference to the sukkah within this passage ("שיש בה ענין סכה").

Where is the reference to the sukkah in Exodus 33:12-34:26?

Comment: What about the end of 34:22?

Comment: @DoubleAA - as per my comment beneath Pakuda's answer, my assumption was that the Mishna Berurah *could* have said "סכת", but chose for whatever reason to say "סכה" instead. But you may be right and he may have been referring to the festival...

Answer (score 1):

I assumed it was a matter of a reference to the holiday of Sukkos, not to a Sukkah.

[Exodus 34:22](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0234.htm#22):

> וְחַג שָׁבֻעֹת תַּעֲשֶׂה לְךָ, בִּכּוּרֵי קְצִיר חִטִּים; וְחַג,
> הָאָסִיף--תְּקוּפַת, הַשָּׁנָה
>
> And thou shalt observe the feast of
> weeks, even of the first-fruits of wheat harvest, and the feast of
> ingathering at the turn of the year.

The "feast of ingathering" (hag ha-asif) is Sukkos.

Comment: Thanks, Paquda... You might be right. My assumption was that while he could have said "שיש בה ענין סכת", he said סכה for a reason. But pending any indications to the contrary, I may have to assume as you did.

Comment: Maybe it would be helpful to check the parallel halakhah for pesah--regarding the reading for hol ha-moed--and see how it's worded. Also, you could check Torah Shleimah on the pasuk that has the word 've-sakkoti' and see if a connection to sukkot was ever made by any midrash.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know for certain, but having now heard that portion leyned in full, I wonder if the Mishna Berurah is referring to Exodus 33:22, in which the verb used to describe God's hand covering Moses' face (ושכותי) is etymologically related to the word used to describe the covering of the sukkah (שכך).